# Access fields inside [{ }] using mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to retrieve the whole document which matches storeId in the below document.

"fuelprices" : [
        {
            "storeId" : 226,
            "merchant" : "M1415",
              (more fields)
                 }
                ]

I tried:
db.FuelStations.find({"fuelprices.storeId": 226})

db.colName.find({"fuelprices.[].storeId": 226}).

The result should return the whole document which matches 226 storeId.

If you could help that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the field as if it was a subject directly. It'll scan each element and match.

```
db.collection.find({
  "fuelprices.storeId": 226
})
```

See [the docs on querying an array of embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. It works if the field was like this fuelprices{ storeId: 226}.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it just now on my mongo install and seems to work. Mongoplayground also says it works. See: https://mongoplayground.net/p/6iL8PuJt6q-

Comment: It worked there, is that because the whole document was inside [ ]? I tried removing the outer [ ] in that playground, it didn't work.

Comment: That's just how mongoplayground works, the outer [] is basically the 'collection'. If you insert just the inner document into a database and run the query it should work. If it doesn't I'll need to see a full object from your database to help you further

Comment: Had to change the syntax a little bit to make mongoplayground accept it but it still works: https://mongoplayground.net/p/1_up5_2oCey I tested the full object in my Mongo install again and it still works there for me too.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. But to change that format in database how do I update those fields without able to access them?

Comment: Updating fields inside an array is a whole new ordeal, The original question didn't mention it. You can do it through the positional identifier and arrayFilters. You'll need to read about them in the mongo docs.

Answer (score 0):

The all positional operator $[] indicates that the update operator should modify all elements in the specified array field.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/

you are missing the $ for your query

Comment: You are right. But mine was 3.2 version. Sorry I didn't mention that in the question.